# BIRT Dataset Parameter Placeholder not Created

Tags: birt

The `BIRT` documentation states that when I add a `?` marker in the `where` clause of the `SQL` query, `BIRT` will automatically create a placeholder parameter that I can then edit appropriately. I've added the markers, but nothing ever appears in the `Parameters` list for the dataset. Am I missing something? If I create a parameter without first having a placeholder, can I somehow associate it with the appropriate marker in the query?

Comment: I don't know what you are missing but we are missing a code example and detailed description of what happens.

Comment: There is no "code" per se, at least not that's directly associated to the issue.  And with regard to "what happens," I believe that is explained. The documentation says that by adding a ? marker into the where clause of query, BIRT will create a corresponding dataset parameter. That isn't "happening." So, what am I missing? Am I misreading the documentation? Is there something I need to do beyond simply adding a ? marker to the query? Is there some way to manually associate a parameter I create with a marker?

Comment: So you did not try to write any code to solve this issue yet? Did you just imagine that nothing happens when you add markers?

Comment: Rolf, are you just being rude? It sure seems that way. If you call writing a SQL statement "writing code," then that's what I have. The where clause is pretty simple: where p.name=? and o.date <= ? and o.date >=?. Again, the issue is that this doesn't generate the placeholder parameters, if that's even what's supposed to happen. It seems like it is from the documentation, but I don't know, which is why I posted the question.

Comment: I do sound kind of rude. It was not my intention, and I regret it. I was in a different state of mind, different perspective. However my query/criticism is legitimate. On SO, you are expected to provide code when the problem is related to a bit of code. You might have omitted a comma somewhere, for example. It happened to me many times. By not posting the particular bit of code that is failing you are not using Stackoverflow to it's full capacity and making it harder for others to help.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are not generated automatically.
You'll have to add them manually.
After finishing the SQL SELECT statement, edit the Data Set and choose the entry "Parameters" from the menu on the left side. Then, for each "?" in the select, add a parameter using the "New..." button on the right side.

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks for setting that straight. I'm curious then, ho does BIRT associate the dataset parameters with the markers, just in order of reference? Anyway, I am placing markers, creating dataset parameters for each, and associating the dataset parameters with report parameters. When I run the report, I get an error stating "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value "1" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-186]." Any ideas? Is it possible to see the actual query being passed to the SQL server?

Comment: Yes, it's just the order of reference. The n-th "?" in the query corresponds to the n-th DS parameter. Therefore it's best to use a statement like WITH params as SELECT ? as p_dname, ? as p_ename from dual SELECT ... from params, DEPT, EMP where params.DNAME like DEPT.DNAME